# About polynomials over extensions of finite fields

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $\Bbb F$ be a finite field of size a prime number $q$, and let $\Bbb K$ be a degree $m$ extension of $\Bbb F$. 
Let $R$ be the polynomial ring $\Bbb K[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$.

Let $f\in\Bbb F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in \Bbb F$ for all $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in \Bbb F^n$.
My question is about the converse of that statement:

> Suppose that $f\in R$ is such that $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in \Bbb F$ for all $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in \Bbb F^n$, is it true that $f\in\Bbb F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$?

**My thoughts so far**

If $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in \Bbb F$ for all $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in \Bbb F^n$ then $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = (f(a_1,\ldots,a_n))^q$ so $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n))^q - f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ defines the zero function on $\Bbb F^n$, therefore it belongs to the ideal over $R$ generated by $x_j^q-x_j$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$.
However, I don't see how to use this to show that to show that the coefficients of $f$ are in $\Bbb F$.

By the way, I don't even know if that claim is true, but I couldn't come up with a counter example.

Any insights about this problem will be very much appreciated!

Comment: $\alpha (x^q-x)$ with $\alpha \not \in \mathbb{F}_q$. Thus you can only say $f \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is the zero polynomial iff it is the zero function on $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$.

Comment: @reuns Ok, in general any polynomial in the ideal. But what if we also add the condition that $f\notin J = \langle x_1^q-x_1,\ldots,x_n^q-x_n\rangle$? i.e. $f(\Bbb F^n)$ is not equal to $\{0\}$

Comment: You didn't get it : $f(x) = \sum_{a \in \mathbb{F}_{q^3}} \frac{x^{q^3}-x}{x-a} v_a \left[\frac{t-a}{t^{q^3}-t}\right]_{t=a}$ then $f(a) = v_a$ for $a \in \mathbb{F}_{q^3}$

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the comment, but it seems I still don't get it. Could you elaborate a bit please on what you're trying to remark with your comment? I think you're trying to give a counter example but I don't see how is this one.

Comment: Of course it is true that $f \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is the zero function on $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ iff $f \in (x^{q}-x)$

Comment: @reuns Indeed... so now you're confusing me. What did you want to prove in a first place? I'm sorry, but I'm not following you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve my question in a very simple manner, at least in the case in which the characteristic $q$ is large enough.

We know that if the degree of the polynomial is $d$, then we need about $\lambda =O(n^d)$ coefficients to represent it. If $\lambda < q^n$, we can treat the coefficients as unknowns and plug into the polynomial a number of tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in\Bbb F^n$ that is larger than $\lambda$.
By doing this we will get a linear system of equations whose solutions (the coefficients) lie in the field $\Bbb F$.